# How do I figure out what the model number is of my Shimano rear derailleur?

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, maintenance, shifter, derailleur-rear

Here are pictures of my current derailleur I need to replace.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It could be a TOURNEY RD-TY300-SGS REAR DERAILLEUR, A close up photo looking toward the axle nut is needed to get a definitive answer. Also knowwing how many gears are on the rear wheel will help.

Comment: Look very closely at it , with a good light - there will be a number of the format "RD-xxx0" and that is the model number which can be searched online for the specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shimano stamps the rear derailleur model number on the underside/lower plate of the parallelogram.  All models for the last several decades.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely one of the models in the Shimano Tourney range.

You don't need to know exact model to replace it. You just need to know what specs the replacement derailleur needs. You can look at the derailleur models in the Tourney lines in the [Shimano Line-Up](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/lc) pages (you might find you exact model by comparing pictures also).

All the specs are pretty self-explanatory apart from *speeds* which is the number of sprockets in the rear cluster and *total capacity* needed which is tooth count difference between largest and smallest sprocket plus tooth count difference between largest and smallest chainrings (if more than one).